# Are there two non-equivalent exotic structures on $\mathbb{R}^4$ coming from topologically slice, non-slice knots?

Tags: differential-topology, knot-theory, 4-manifolds, heegaard-floer-homology, khovanov-homology

For a knot $K \subset S^3$, which is topologically slice but not slice (in a smooth way), there's a four manifold $\mathbb{R}^4_K$, homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to standard euclidean $\mathbb{R}^4$.

There are ways to find such knots, particularly knots with the Alexander polynomial equal to 1, are topologically slice (Freedman). Among these knots one can find non-slice knots using obstructions like $\tau$-invariant (coming from Knot Floer Homology) or Rasmussen $s$-invariant (coming from Khovanov Homology). Knots with non-zero $\tau$- or $s$- invariant are not slice.

The negative Whitehead double of left trefoil is an example of these knots.

Question. The above argument proves the existence of an exotic structure on  $\mathbb{R} ^4$, but this method proves the existence of only one exotic structure on $\mathbb{R} ^4$. Can you show if there are two different knots, $K$ and $K'$ (both topologically slice, non-slice knots), which they give us two non-equivalent exotic $\mathbb{R} ^4$s? Or if all of $\mathbb{R}_K^4$ coming from these knots are the same, i.e. you can get to only one exotic structure through this method.